# Non-monotonicity

Tags: real-analysis, functions

I know that a function is $f$ said to be strictly monotonic on $[a,b]$ if

- $x<y; x,y \in [a,b] \implies f(x)<f(y)$
  or
- $x<y; x,y \in [a,b] \implies f(x)>f(y)$

I have an intuition that if $f$ is not strictly monotonic, then 
$\exists c \in (a,b)$ & $ \delta >0$ such that $f(c)\geq f(x) \forall x \in [c-\delta,c+\delta]$ or $f(c)\leq f(x) \forall x \in [c-\delta,c+\delta]$. 
However, I am not able to prove it or disprove it.

Please help me out with this. Thanks!

Comment: This would only be true for continuous functions

Comment: But how? Can you please give some hint on how to approach to prove it?

Comment: Have you tried a delta-epsilon approach? Maybe IVT?

Answer (score 1):

It's true when $f$ is continuous. For non-continuous $f$, you can have for instance
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1,&\ x\in\mathbb Q\\ 0,&\ x\not\in\mathbb Q\end{cases}
$$
which will fail your property on any interval.

So assume $f$ continuous. If $f$ is not monotonic and not constant, there should exist $x,y,z$ such that $f(x)< f(y)$ and $f(y)>f(z)$ (or vice versa). Since $f$ is continuous on $[x,y]$, it achieves its maximum at some $c\in[x,y]$. As $f(c)\geq f(y)>f(z)$ and $f(c)\geq f(y)>f(x)$, we have $c\in(x,y)$. Now take $\delta>0$ such that $(c-\delta,c+\delta)\subset(x,y)$.